# secured user authentification within a phonegap app

Tags: security, authentication, mobile, cordova, oauth

I'm developing a mobile application with PhoneGap and I'm stuck on the member login.

I want to set up a RESTful API to communicate between this mobile app and my web app. This actually doesn't cause any problem.
My problem is how to secure the user authentification and the communications between the server and the client (the mobile app).

I don't want to use HTTP Basic Authentification because both username and password are visible.
I could have used Digest Authentification but I quickly understood that it is hard to use with Ajax and is almost not so secure.

I've read lots of articles about OAuth. Is it the best solution for me? I have both consumer (mobile app) and provider access (web app) so I can do everything.

What would look like my login form? Do I need to open the login form in a ChildBrowser on the server side, get the request token then the access token, and by location change close the ChildBrowser and store the access token on the mobile phone?

I've seen that kind of trick here http://www.wisejive.com/2010/11/phonegap-jquery-mobile-twitter-and.html ..

Please help me I really don't find the best secure solution for my RESTful API..